# How to improve imageView appear from behind

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have two imageViews , one is over another one. When I do a scroll gesture, the below one will appear in front. What I am not satisfied is that, the pic below will appear suddenly. The effect I want to get is gradually appear. You can have a look at [this website](http://www.imgmodels.com/details.aspx?cityID=1&modelid=148544&agencyID=&from=&pic=059.jpg&hd=por&subid=5570&mainsubid=5570&catID=3&indx=1) (Try changing pic). Can any one give me some clues about achieving this or some advise to improve imageview appear from behind?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a animation to gradually change the alpha of the imageView from 0 to 1. This will achieve your desired affect.

Something like this...

```
imageView.alpha = 0;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
        animations:^{
            imageView.alpha = 1;
        }
        completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're description sounds like you just want a simple cross-fade, as the other poster suggested.

However, the link you posted looks like a coverflow style animation. Is that what you are after? If you search on GitHub, there are a couple of open source libraries that let you do that. It's fairly complex Core Animation.